# Cannot POST /api/auth/login%0A posman error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, post

Now Iam making an app on node.js and express and met such an error while makin post requests in Postman

```
Cannot POST /api/auth/login%0A
```

I include here app.js , auth.js, controller.js files

app.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth')
const analyticsRoutes = require('./routes/analytics')
const categoryRoutes = require('./routes/category')
const orderRoutes = require('./routes/order')
const positionRoutes = require('./routes/position')
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())


app.use('/api/auth', authRoute);
app.use('/api/analytics', analyticsRoutes);
app.use('/api/category', categoryRoutes);
app.use('/api/order', orderRoutes);
app.use('/api/position', positionRoutes);
```

auth.js
also are the same routes/files like analytics, order, position in controllers folder but they are empty now.

```js
const express = require('express');
const controller = require('../controller/auth');
//const analytics = require('../controller/analytics')
const router = express.Router();

//localhost:5000/api/auth/login/

router.post('login', controller.login)
router.post('/register', controller.register)

module.exports = router;
```

auth.js (in controller folder)

```js
module.exports.login = function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({
    login: {
      email: req.body.email,
      pass: req.body.pass
    }
  });
}

module.exports.register = function(req, res) {


}
```

```js
const app = require('./app');

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;




app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server has been started from port ${port}`))
```

index.js
get requests in browser are working but post are not in postman. I tryed to use bodyparser but it not work. In postman I enter data correctly. pass and login in json.

The structure of folders
index.js
app.js
---routes
auth.js
order.js ...
---controllers
auth.js
order.js ...

Comment: Please provide how you're setting up postman call to make sure issue is not related to how you're using the tool. Also looking at your code you're missing / in login endpoint

Comment: ok I will look on Postman settings, thanks

Comment: I solved it using requst without http:// in postman and now it works fine
something like localhost:5000/api/auth/login

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to follow along the code, but try to add a forward slash on your login route in routes/auth.js

```
router.post('login', controller.login) -> router.post('/login', controller.login)
```

Also you don't need to use Bodyparser. You can use express for the same thing in app.js:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: thanks for this tip with express but I added '/' and the same error happens

Comment: Have you set the Content-Type: application/json in Postman?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue then I checked this page and erased http from the URL and changed the port number.
Now It's working for me

Answer (score 0):

faced the same problem , and i solved it by changing the port number

Comment: This is more a comment than a answear, please share the command you used to be more assertive and helpful

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31369857)